# Importing gradle library into Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gradle, android-library

Eclipse is where i am building my Android application and currently i cannot switch to Android studio.

I need to add **small circular countdowntimer on actionbar**. What i am trying is use CircleProgress library available on github but issue is it using gradle and i don't know what is Gradle. I tried few steps here like making java folder source or creating new library but none of them is working.

[link for library](https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress)

Error its showing is **Error parsing XML: unbound prefix**

My layout File Source:-

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:weightSum="10" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llcount"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@color/Black"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgQuit"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/quit_icon" />

        <com.youth4work.prepapp.CustomTextViewFont
            android:id="@+id/txtquesno"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Daily Test - Q1/Q20"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />

        <com.youth4work.prepapp.CustomTextViewFont
            android:id="@+id/txttimer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/barTimer"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar" />

        <com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.DonutProgress //Error over here
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/donut_progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        custom:donut_progress="30"/>
    </LinearLayout>
      <!--  Further Code and then closed Main LinearLayout -->
```

help me solve this issue.
  Also it will be helpful if someone can provide me good refrence for what is gradle and why we must we use it, so that i can be prepare next time.

**Edit**

here's my builds.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0@aar'
}
version = "1.2.0"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 5
        versionName version
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

def siteUrl = 'https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress'
def gitUrl = 'https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress.git'
group = "com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress"
install {
    repositories.mavenInstaller {
        // This generates POM.xml with proper parameters
        pom {
            project {
                packaging 'aar'
                // Add your description here
                name 'Circle Progress, Donut Progress, Arc Progress'
                url siteUrl
                // Set your license
                licenses {
                    license {
                        name 'MIT'
                        url 'http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT'
                    }
                }
                developers {
                    developer {
                        id 'lzyzsd'
                        name 'Bruce Lee'
                        email 'bruceinpeking@gmail.com'
                    }
                }
                scm {
                    connection gitUrl
                    developerConnection gitUrl
                    url siteUrl
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}
task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}
task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}
artifacts {
    archives javadocJar
    archives sourcesJar
}
Properties properties = new Properties()
properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
bintray {
    user = properties.getProperty("bintray.user")
    key = properties.getProperty("bintray.apikey")
    configurations = ['archives']
    pkg {
        repo = "maven"
        name = "CircleProgress"
        websiteUrl = siteUrl
        vcsUrl = gitUrl
        licenses = ["MIT"]
        publish = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Just use Android studio like everyone else.

Comment: @JaredBurrows i had mentioned something on first. If you know answer that provide it else don't waste time of yours and mine.

Answer (score 1):

As it says [on the GitHub site](https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress), you add the libraries to your project with the following code in your `build.gradle` script:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0@aar'
}
```

To then make those available to eclipse, run the following gradle tasks: `cleanEclipse eclipse`

You can do this on the command line via the gradle wrapper, or presumably within your eclipse environment if you have it setup correctly (I don't personally use eclipse's gradle integration, I use the wrapper and run gradle on the command line)

This will regenerate your eclipse classpath and include the circleprogress libs. If you refresh your project in eclipse, you should see them in the dependency list.

Your project must have the following at the top of your build.gradle script:

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
```

**EDIT:**  Additional information about gradle wrapper.

See the [official documentation for gradle wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html).

If you have a file "gradlew" or "gradlew.bat" in the project directory, you can run this on the command line (cmd). For windows, it's just normal cmd. For linux, any normal shell.

cd into your project directory and type

```
gradlew.bat cleanEclipse eclipse
```

or in linux

```
./gradlew cleanEclipse eclipse
```

Your eclipse project may already have gradle support, in which case you have to follow its method for running the gradle tasks.

Comment: Where to add those dependencies at top or at last?

Comment: i have apply plugin at top and then this dependencies but its showing builds failed

Comment: Add your build script to your question. I suspect you don't have a `apply plugin: 'java'` at the top, above the dependencies section. Gradle won't do anything unless you tell it what plugins you want to load. You need as a minimum `java` and `eclipse` loaded to do any compilation and have it make an eclipse project.

Comment: thanks for that info. I am trying and get new comiplation error and one was that. working now but some new error as cannot add task ':library:javadoc' as task with same name already exist. Thanks for your help. I have now understood and will surely make it Work. Thanks Again. I will make it as answer once i sort all  out.

Comment: hey i have updated my code with builds script. please help me out in solving error  cannot add task ':library:javadoc' as a task with same name exist

Comment: Builds succesful and imported in eclipse but still my error parsing xml is not solved